# Outlook keyboard shortcut to format a reply into plain text?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2013, plaintext

Is there a keyboard shortcut available in Outlook (2013) to format an email reply I am writing into plain text? (N.B. Unlike [this questioner](https://superuser.com/q/587547/166855) I want to maintain the format of the incoming message as I read it, but when I reply want a quick mouse-free way of converting to plain text.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a keyboard shortcut, using the native ribbon structure in Outlook 2013, which will do the following to the REPLY mail ( You can read email in HTML)

1. Formatted text will become plain text
2. Pictures will be lost
3. Tables will be lost

This shortcut works, when you use the Pop-Out Compose mail.

Hit <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>

Onetime pop out will appear for confirmation

[image]

Once you confirm it, the whole mail in the Compose window would turn to plain text.

Hope you like this solution.

Comment: I do! That Alt + o will prove dead useful too, thank you